# Spring boot gradle build and push docker image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I trying to build and push the docker image to my docker hub.After building 90% I am getting error

```
D:\demo>gradlew jib

> Task :jib

Containerizing application to nithin4325/my-java-image...

Container entrypoint set to [java, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*,
 com.example.demo.DemoApplication]
Executing tasks:
[===========================   ] 90.0% complete
> building image to registry

    > Task :jib FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':jib'.
    > com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build
    image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'nithin4325/my-j
    ava-image' are set up correctly.
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '1.4.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jib{
    to
       {
        image = 'nithin4325/my-java-image'
       }
   }

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

I am using windows 7 professional having docker toolbox.I already logged in to dockerhub through command prompt using `docker login`.

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin Make sure you have a docker-credential-helper set up. For example, on macOS, the credential helper would be docker-credential-osxkeychain. See Authentication Methods for other ways of authenticating.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli { "credsStore": "wincred"}  when I add to config.json and try to login getting error  Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credent ial-wincred": executable file not found in %PATH%, out: ``

Comment: You are on windows this should be wincred https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers#available-programs

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added and still getting same error and my config.json is like this {
 "auths": {
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
 },
 "HttpHeaders": {
  "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.1 (windows)"
 },
 "credsStore": "wincred"
}

Comment: When i debug I am getting like this  ------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.
docker.io",scope="repository:nithin4325/my-java-image:pull,push",error="invalid_
token"
Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2020 04:52:04 GMT
Content-Length: 250
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000